# Performance of lazy evaluation in Haskell when the arguments appear several times

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Let's say I have a function which can calculate power of four of a number defined by

```
let power4 x = x*x*x*x
```

And I try to pass x = (3 + 8)*2

```
let result = power4 ((3 + 8)*2)
```

Since in Haskell, the values are evaluated until they are needed, does it mean that x will evaluate four times? If so, is there any way to improve the Haskell compiler?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK the haskell-compiler is smart enough to use caching in such cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you aren't sure, you could use `trace` to check (ref: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging):

```
import Debug.Trace

power4 x = x*x*x*x

main = print $ power4 (trace "called" ((3+8)*2))
```

result:

```
called
234256
```

so the expression is only evaluated once.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to use the original (3+8)*2 instead of 4 (I found it confusing with 4); hope you don't mind. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Thanks. The expression should be wrapped in `(` ... `)` though, otherwise it will be `(trace "called" (3+8)) * 2`.

Comment: I also tend to check implementation behaviour with that trick. For instance, `power4 x = (trace "called" x)*(trace "called" x)*(trace "called" x)*(trace "called" x)` will output `"called"` once if compiled with optimization and four times otherwise. In this case, I think this correctly illustrates what really happens (I thought it was CSE kicking-in but GHC does not perform CSE for that kind of construct, must be something else). Still, I wonder if it's always a correct general inspection procedure given that `trace` is using `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 10):

No, it will only be evaluated once.  In *call by name* it would be evaluated four times, but all Haskell implementations are *call by need* (although the standard does not require this), which means each expression will be evaluated *at most* once.

This only applies when the expression is fully concrete.  E.g. there is no guarantee that in:

```
foo x = x + (1+2)

bar = foo 3 + foo 4
```

That when computing `bar`, `(1+2)` will be evaluated only once. In fact, it will probably be evaluated twice (if compiled without optimizations).

Comment: Could you explain "fully concrete"?

Comment: Can the compiler not completely remove 1+2 from the runtime? At least if `foo :: Int -> Int`. — Regardless, what you say is at any rate true for `foo x y = x + (1+y)` `bar = foo 3 2 + foo 4 2`: here `(1+y)` (=`1+2`) will certainly be evaluated twice.